# How do I move a RemoteApp window using the keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

In Windows, you can normally use the Win-left/right arrow keys to move and resize a window to occupy the left/right half of a screen.
When using a Remote Desktop in full-screen mode, this also works.
But when I run a RemoteApp, this method fails. This function is never included in lists of keyboard shortcuts I've found on the internet, so I suspect it's not possible by default. Is there a way to obtain this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, RemoteApp does not support docking: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/954401/ - so this is not possible, not with a mouse / touch or a keyboard.